# Install gcc on a computing cluster without root privilege and no c compiler installed

Tags: linux, gcc

Currently I realise that my computing cluster do not have gcc, g++, gfortran and therefore I cannot compile c file or install python libraries with gcc support. I do not have the root privilege of the computing cluster, I cannot use "yum install" or "sudo apt install" to install gcc. So I download the gcc-11.1.0 tar.gz file in my local computer and then upload to the cluster and install it. When I ./configure the gcc, the error messages appear:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for libhsail-rt support... yes
checking for libphobos support... yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

I do know that the error comes from no c compiler in the cluster. That is the reason why I want to install gcc to have a c compiler. So I got stuck in the loop where install gcc needs c compiler but I don't have a c compiler such that I download gcc. My problem is that how can I install a c compiler without root privilege and except downloading gcc? I appreciate any comment.

Comment: Yes, you will need a C compiler to compile gcc sources. You can try to find a binary of any C compiler (almost anyone would do with gcc sources, the ones needed for first phase are super simple) and upload it on your compute cluster. If you can't find such binary distributed C compiler, you can try cross-compiling something locally and upload it to compute cluster.

Comment: What [linux] distro is on your desktop/laptop (_not_ the cluster) (e.g. fedora, ubuntu, etc.)? You can download the source there and cross-compile for the target. But, you should be able to extract the binary package `.rpm` and convert it to a tar file and copy that to the target. From your log, the target is an x86_64 so the binaries on your laptop should be compatible

Comment: Thank you for your comment @SergeyA. Yes, I have a similar viewpoint that find a C compiler and then install it on the cluster first. However, I could not find any other C compiler since people usually suggest to use gcc or use sudo apt install. It is rare that downloading a C compiler on cluster without root / gcc.

Comment: Hi, @CraigEstey. I am using the M1 MacBook to connect the cluster. I am new to use cluster and I don't have much computer science background, I do not know how to cross-compile the gcc. Is there any good reference for me to learn cross-compiling?

Comment: It's not relevant what you using to connect. It's relevant what you connect to. What linux distribution is running on the cluster? Most probably centos, does `cat /etc/centos-release` print something?

Comment: Hi, @KamilCuk. I am not sure what "linux distribution" means. I type "cat /etc/os-release" on the terminal and it says NAME="CentOS Linux" , ID_LIKE="rhel fedora".

Comment: Sure - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution - then it's centos. What would `rpm -q centos-release` print? In any case, I strongly believe you should ask some admin of _that cluster_ for help, _instead_ of asking on an internet forum.

Comment: @KamilCuk OP's laptop is an M1 macOS, so it's not linux and is arm not x86--a double whammy.

Answer (score 0):

There are vast multiple solutions you can take. For example:

- Use docker, if available.
- Download whole chroot of your favorite distribution. And chroot into it.

  - If you can't chroot, use proot.
  - If you can't proot, run the interpreter from chroot explicitly with the executable path and arguments from chroot and setup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (and maybe some `LD_PRELOAD`).
  - if the remote pc does not allow network connection, download stuff to chroot by chroot-ing into it on your pc, then copy it to the remote.
- use nix package manager
- use pkgsrc package manger
- download gcc source to your computer, download dependencies from the remote (glibc, interpreter, headers, maybe some more) to your computer and cross-compile gcc to destination environment and copy the result
- just get what distribution is running on the remote and download packaged gcc executable from that distribution package manager repositories

I recommend nix, if it does not work, proot to your favorite Linux distribution.

You would want to research: `PATH` environment variable, dynamic linker/loader, and `man ld.so` and `LD_*` variables configuration, thus how `chroot` (and `docker`) works, about user namespaces (thus how `proot` works).